# Why was this question incorrectly closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[Has North Korea threatened a preemptive strike on the USA or its allies?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/has-north-korea-threatened-a-preemptive-strike-on-the-usa-or-its-allies)

Why was the above question closed as off-topic.  The question was closed with no explanation given, but the question does fit the FAQ.

If it was because the title used to read "Is North Korea planning a ...", then why wasn't a comment simply made asking to change the title, since the body of the question was about their supposed threats rather than their actual plans.

I request that this question be re-opened, or suggestions be made for how I can edit the question to meet community standards.

I'm also curious which current electoral candidates support the closure of this question.

Comment: Also why is this question here:  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/was-the-usa-colonized-by-criminals, with a vote of -1, and no notability claim at all left open?  Where is the consistency?

Comment: Everyone, we just need one more re-open vote.  Someone please!

Answer (score 1):

The previous title - the previous *question* you posed - was clearly off topic because it was about secret motivations and basically invited pure speculation.

This has been corrected but the problem now lies in the answers, which are referring to the previous title.

They should be revised before reopening.

Comment: What do you mean?  The accepted answer addresses the current question title, not the former.  The question states what the North Koreans have said, compared with what Western Media has said.  I also think this applies to the second, not accepted answer.

Comment: I think the people answered the question based on the content, not based on the question title.